# Slack API to query direct messages count between users

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm trying to see if they is a way to use the slack API to query how many messages two users are sending

From the API documents I think it should be using https://api.slack.com/types/im but I'm unsure how to query it

Any help will be good

Answer (score 0):

The API looks like, it's not supposed to return absolute information like the count of the messages. But with the [`im.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.history) you can get all messages and just count them. But for long chats this has a big overhead of getting all these messages. Also there's a limit to the `count` of messages you can query, so you might have to query all iteratively.